# Hiding certain rows of a table using JS, if

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table set up as such:

```
<table id="Table" class="sortable">
<col class="quantity"></col>
<col class="price"></col>
<col class="total"></col>
<thead>
<tr>    
<th class="right">Quantity</th>
<th class="right">Price</th>
<th class="right">Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="right">50,000</td>
<td class="right" sorttable_customkey="10.25">10.25</td>
<td class="right" sorttable_customkey="512500">512,500</td>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="right">1,250</td>
<td class="right" sorttable_customkey="8.1">8.10</td>
<td class="right" sorttable_customkey="101125">101,125</td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using JavaScript, how can I hide rows based on the quantity of one or more cells? Like if (the price is less than 5), or (the price is less than 10 and quantity is greater than 1,000), have the whole row skipped over.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I'll admit I haven't tried anything. I have basic Java knowledge, and I just got lost attempting to piece together other cases that did some but not all for what I was looking for.

Comment: @user2041304: I think we know what you meant by "Java", but keep in mind: Java and Javascript are completely different languages.  We'll assume you meant "Javascript".

Comment: No, I meant Java. The if statement and the condition of a for loop would be the only thing I could have done off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only answering this because the horrendous jQuery answer needs to have a substitute.

Place the following in a `<script>` tag anywhere after the table:

```
(function() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('Table'),
        rows = tbl.tBodies[0].children, l = rows.length, i,
        filter = function(cells) {
            var values = [
                parseInt(cells[0].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/,/g,''),10),
                parseFloat(cells[1].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/,/g,'')),
                parseFloat(cells[2].firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/,/g,''))
            ];
            // THIS IS WHERE YOUR CONDITIONS GO
            if( values[1] < 5) return false;
            if( values[1] < 10 && values[0] > 1000) return false;
            return true;
        };
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( !filter(rows[i].cells)) rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
})();
```

Comment: Perfect. Added a row at the top saying how many were being hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you could do something like

```
$.each($('tr'), function(tri, tr) {
    var $tr = $(tr),
        price = parseFloat($tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text()replace(/,/g, "")),
        quantity = parseInt($tr.find('td:first-child').text()replace(/,/g, ""));
    if (price < 5) $tr.hide(); 
    //repeat for other conditions, like if(price < 10 && quantity > 1000)
});
```

As to why you might prefer using a library like jQuery for a task like this instead of using vanilla js, I've found that jQuery selectors and methods like `text()` are easier to write and much easier to read than their counterparts in plain JavaScript.  In addition, I find that I have to rewrite code a lot less when it's done with jQuery selectors than when it's done by manually traversing the DOM.  For instance, if the markup changes to include links or styled elements, this code won't need to be updated.

```
<tr>
<td class="right">1,250</td>
<td class="right" sorttable_customkey="8.1"><span class="low_price">8.10</span></td>
<td class="right" sorttable_customkey="101125">101,125</td>
</td>
</tr>
```

In the above example, the markup has changed; the price is now contained within a `<span>` tag, which might be used for styling certain priced items differently.  Your application's markup may never change, but these things do happen.  When they do, it's nice to have readable code that's easy to change if necessary, and even nicer when your code doesn't have to change.

Comment: I am in full support of jQuery in theory. In practice, however, it is horribly overused and a bulky nightmare.